# Textfield material design

Tags: kotlin, material-design, textfield

I changed my layouts to textfield in material design but now I got error message "Val cannot be reassigned" in following code:

```
binding.istwert.editText = binding.inhalt.editText
```

I only want to copy the text from one textfield to the other.

Definition of binding is:

```
private lateinit var binding: MedikamenteEingabeBinding
```

Does anyone know why this error occures?

Answer (score 0):

What you're currently trying to do is copy the entire EditText (which isn't allowed), that's... not what you should do

if you want to copy the text of one editText to another one, just do:

```kotlin
binding.istwert.text = binding.inhalt.text
```

Comment: Thank you JustSightseeing but .text seems not to be available in material design.
This was working in the past when I used "normal" layout.